# 2004 Toyota Sienna soft brake woes

Tags: brakes, brake-fluid, hydraulic-pressure

Been a mechanic for 20 years now. Wife has a 2004 Toyota Sienna XLE Limited AWD. This car has been a huge pain in the neck for me the entire time we have owned it. Great car, sucks to work on.

A year ago, she would sit at a stop light and after a bit she would notice that the car would start to creep forward. I verified this, then diagnosed it as a bad master cylinder. Pads and rotors were new, all hardware clean and greased.

After a month, the car started exhibiting the same symptoms with the new master cylinder. I warrantied it out and replaced it.

After about another month, same thing. This time I went and bought the Toyota computer system and bled the brakes via OBD. Worked like a charm, lasted about 6 months. Then it started doing the same thing again.

With 195k on the clock, I figured maybe the calipers were hanging. Replaced the fronts, replaced pads and rotors, bled with computer. Worked great. Now it is doing it yet again.

I have bled this stupid car with a hydraulic bleeder, a suction bleeder, with the computer, and with the old fashioned method. It stays good for a week and then goes back to its shenanigans. I figured maybe the piece behind the master is bad, but you can't get that bit without buying a booster from Toyota, which is about $850.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Seems like the abs unit itself is all that's left. I assume there's no abs codes.

Comment: It could be your vacuum booster. What does the pedal feel like when it starts to creep forward? If you disable ABS does it still happen? Obviously you'd want to be really careful how you test that.

Comment: Jupiter- No, no ABS codes.

Comment: GdB- I don't think that it's the booster because the pedal would be hard, not mushy.